# image not loading using json from url

Tags: android, json

Here is my code. 
The image space remaining empty. Not being loaded. 
What is my mistake here?
what kind of code i need again.
give more definition pls.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private ListView listView;

        // JSON data url
        private static String Jsonurl = "http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors";
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactJsonList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            contactJsonList = new ArrayList<>();
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            new GetContacts().execute();
        }

        private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Showing progress dialog
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                HTTPHandler httpHandler = new HTTPHandler();

                // request to json data url and getting response
                String jsonString = httpHandler.makeServiceCall(Jsonurl);
                Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonString);
                if (jsonString != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        JSONArray contacts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("actors");

                        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                            String name = c.getString("name");
                            String country = c.getString("country");
                            String spouse = c.getString("spouse");
                            String dob = c.getString("dob");
                            String description = c.getString("description");
                            String children = c.getString("children");
                            String image = c.getString("image");

                            // tmp hash map for single contact
                            HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            contact.put("name", name);
                            contact.put("country", country);
                            contact.put("spouse", spouse);
                            contact.put("dob", dob);
                            contact.put("description", description);
                            contact.put("children", children);
                            contact.put("image", image);

                            // adding contact to contact list
                            contactJsonList.add(contact);
                        }
                    } catch (final JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not get json from server.");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not get json from server.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                /**     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView    * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactJsonList, R.layout.row,
                        new String[]{"name","country", "spouse", "dob", "description", "children", "image"},
                        new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.country, R.id.spouse, R.id.dob, R.id.description, R.id.children, R.id.imageview});

                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }
```

thanks for your help

Comment: The image you are reading I guess it is a URL. So you have to load your bitmap from the image url inside your adapter. So check your adapter code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load image from URL Use custom adapter and use picasso or Glide library to load image.
or
If you want to use simpleAdapter then check this link [Image from URL in ListView using SimpleAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314314/image-from-url-in-listview-using-simpleadapter)

Answer (score 0):

you can user Glide library to load image from url look the below code it can help you in simple way

**compile this library**

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
```

**than load image like this**

```
Glide.with(HomeClass.this)
            .load(userProfileUrl)
            .centerCrop()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .dontAnimate()
            .into(imageview);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to load list of images from url? then
check out the link below, there is detailed example working with list of images using json with volly library.
[Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

I hope this will help you.